# Wifi disconnection Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: wireless, drivers, disconnect

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 on an HP 15-n209tx. I know this issue has been asked about several times before but I have not been able to solve my issue so far. When i boot up my OS, the WiFi connects very well. But while I am browsing, the Wifi disconnects on its own and asks for the wifi password for reconnection. 
I have ran the 
$sudo lshw -C network
command and here is the output for the same

> `*-network
>
>          description: Wireless interface
>          product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
>          vendor: Ralink corp.
>          physical id: 0
>          bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
>          logical name: wlan0
>          version: 00
>          serial: 48:5a:b6:c5:58:4d
>          width: 32 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>          configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.19.0-15-generic firmware=0.37 ip=172.16.225.231 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
>          resources: irq:18 memory:b5510000-b551ffff
>     *-network
>          description: Ethernet interface
>          product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
>          vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>          physical id: 0
>          bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
>          logical name: eth0
>          version: 08
>          serial: a0:1d:48:df:52:f8
>          size: 10Mbit/s
>          capacity: 100Mbit/s
>          width: 64 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
>          configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
>          resources: irq:43 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b5404000-b5404fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff`

What should I do now? I am new to Ubuntu, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried disabling "NOACK" in your router settings